# draw feature in ol3 using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, openlayers

Attempting to emit a geometry after the feature is drawn on tab 1. Then trying to redraw the feature using socket.on to be displayed on tab 2. however for some reason the feature is not drawn.

```
window.onload = function init() {
  var source = new ol.source.Vector({ wrapX: false });
  //create a base vector layer to draw on
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source,
  });

  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  //create map
  map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [raster, vector],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 10
    })
  });

  function drawShape(value) {

      var value = value;
      if (value !== 'None') {
          draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
              source: source,
              type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (value)
          });
          map.addInteraction(draw);

          draw.on('drawend', function (event) {

            // Get the array of features
            var feature = event.feature

            try {
                map.removeInteraction(draw);
                socket.emit('new polygon', feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                socket.emit('chat message', feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
            } catch (err) { }
          });
      }
  }

  var socket = io();
  socket.on('new polygon', function (msg) {

      var thing = new ol.geom.Polygon(msg);

      var featurething = new ol.Feature({
          name: "Thing",
          geometry: thing
      });

      source.addFeature(featurething);

  });
}
```

when the script is run the msg contains an array of coordinates. Nothing appears in the console.

[image: msg value]

I am a beginner at node.js. anyone know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Can you add some example output from your node.js script? What does `msg` in your `socket.on` look like? Any browser console errors from openlayers?

Comment: this has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. In your `socket.on` callback you are calling

```
source.addFeatures(featurething);
```

when it should be

```
source.addFeature(featurething); // single feature, no s
```

or

```
source.addFeatures([featurething]); // put it in an array
```